# Set up numbers into MultiLevel tree

Tags: vba, excel, tree, binary-tree, multi-level

I need to generate numbers into column F, based on hierarchy (col B:D). Below is excel examaple and also result/values which should I get.
[image]

I know only how to display values for Level1. Here is my code:

```
ws_c = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Lev1 As Long, Lev2 As Long, Lev3 As Long
Lev1 = 1
    For i = 3 To ws_c        
        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
           ws1.Range("F" & i).Value = Lev1
           Lev1 = Lev1 + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: first, fully qualify your `ws_c` by changing to `ws_c = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row` , on the following line define your variables correctly, it should be `Dim Lev1 As Long, Lev2 As Long, Lev3 As Long`

Comment: I have corrected the above code as you wrote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I did it:

```
For i = 3 To ws_c
    '**************************************************************** L1
    If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
       ws1.Range("F" & i).Value = Lev1
       Lev1 = Lev1 + 1
       Lev2 = 100
    End If
    '**************************************************************** L1.1
    If ws1.Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
        ws1.Range("F" & i).Value = Lev2 + Lev1 - 1
        Lev2 = Lev2 + 100            
        Lev3 = 10000
    End If
    '**************************************************************** L1.1.1
    If ws1.Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
        ws1.Range("F" & i).Value = Lev3 + Lev1 - 1 + Lev2 - 100
        Lev3 = Lev3 + 10000
    End If
Next
```